# files and data base lost after a c# application update

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, clickonce, updates

I installed a desktop application on a pc that i developed by c# that use an SQL database. After few months, i published a new version of the application (using clickonce) and put it on an FTP server.

When i did the update, the database (.mdf and .ldf files) was erased and replaced by a new one (i think by the one published) so months of work was gone !!!

I am wondering if it is possible to recover or retrieve the old database.

Before doing the update on the pc, i did some tests on my laptop and the local database was never replaced or erased.

Many thanks,

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a programming question. If you keep regular backups (u should btw), you can recover it from there. Or u can give a shot to Windows Restore maybe. You should not publish your sdf file (assuming u r using SQL Server CE) as part of the solution either.

Comment: Are you using entity framework modelling with code first approach?

Comment: No we are not. But the real question is how can we buckup the erased database (if there is a way)

Answer (score 0):

You may check in the PROPERTIES of your solution if the SQL files are set to COPY LOCAL or COPY TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY.

Normally, database files must be set:

```
  Build Action: NONE
  Copy to Output Directory:  Do NOT COPY
```

and you copy them manually during your INSTALL application.

Probably, they´re set to copy and your ClickOnce may provided this.

Comment: But are there a way to buckup the erased database?

Comment: The problem is not related directy to the backup. And yes, you can allow user to make MDF backups (use Filecopy function to a .BAK file). But remember: the problem is about take off the MDF file from install/update, otherwise, all updates will ever rewrite the database file.